# Delete a photo from camera intent

Tags: android

I have a camera intent to capture images for an application.It saves images on tick click. But on cross button click a image is also saved.

How to delete a photo from camera intent in android?

Please help me with a code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

> How to delete a photo from camera intent in android?

If you supplied `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`, see if there is an image written to the location that you specified. If so, delete it.

You can also see if the `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()` contains a `Uri`. It is not supposed to, but some buggy camera apps put one there. If it does, and it has a `file` scheme, you could try deleting the underlying file.

Beyond that, the behavior of the user's chosen camera app is up to the developers of that camera app, not you. If you want that control, write your own camera code, using the camera APIs directly (e.g., `android.hardware.Camera`, `android.hardware.camera2.*`) or via wrapper libraries (e.g., Fotoapparat, CameraKit-Android).