# Delete Record from Camera Intent

Tags: android

How to delete photo from camera intent when a user clicks on cross sign.I developed an application where the tick sign saves the photo in file ,Also the cross sign saves the photo to file.How to delete that photo?Please help me.Below is the code that I have done so far.

```
public void Photo(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File photoFile = null;


        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));

        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP);

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            saveJson();
        }
        else if(requestCode==ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP&&resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED){
           //delete
        }
    }


    File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        File storageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("GeoPark");
        File myDir = new File(storageDirectory, FILENAME1);
        if (myDir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = myDir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                new File(myDir, children[i]).delete();
            }
        }
        else{
            myDir.mkdirs();


        }
        File file = new File(myDir, timestamp);
        return file;

    }
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50121458/115145

Comment: Can you still answer

Comment: no answer was found in the duplicate

Comment: [This is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50121507/115145) in the duplicate question.

Comment: Its the same question again . Seems from same user .

Comment: but how to delete

Comment: `,Also the cross sign saves the photo to file`. No. If the operation is cancelled a file is not created. Please specify device and used camera app.

Comment: device is one plus x and i am using camera intent

Comment: @greenapps refer my code done

Comment: ???? What should i see there. Has something been added?

Comment: `and i am using camera intent`. Yes we know. We see that in your code. But which camera app is used by the user? If that intent does not let the user choose between installed camera apps then install some extra camera apps and inverstigate how they behave. This one you use now does not act normal.

Comment: `new File(myDir, timestamp);`. Nobody can see what is timestamp type and value. You should post better code.

Comment: timestamp is a String that contains DateTime